Evans Chapter 8.4 Notation $\int_{U}{D\mathbf{u} : D\mathbf{v} dx}$
I encountered this notation in Evans Chapter 8.4 (page 471 of the book, page 474 of the PDF file), where $u, v: \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^m$. Under this setup, $D\mathbf{u}$ is the Jacobian matrix. I'm not sure what is $D\mathbf{u} : D\mathbf{v}$. It seems like $D\mathbf{u} : D\mathbf{v}$ should be a scalar function. Then is "$:$ " the Hardamard product of two matrices? Thank you in advance!

check out Appendix A.1, this is the standard inner product of matrices

Thanks Stratos!

When dealing with two second-order tensors, the notation $:$ means a double contraction. Usually, the convention is to reverse the order of indices in each tensor, i.e $S:T=S^i{}jT^j{}i=S{ij}T^{ji}$. Of course the distinction is irrelevant when the tensors are symmetric, but that is not the case here, so you will need to check carefully in the notation appendix to make sure he does not mean $S{ij}T^{ij}$.
